# If i change the transformer on my inverter for a bigger one, will it increase the watts?

Tags: transformer, watts

If i change the transformer on my inverter for a bigger one, will it increase the watts?

Comment: Bigger _how_? Which watts? *It's difficult to tell what is being asked here*

Comment: I actually think the question is reasonably easy to parse. I'll give it a >95% likelihood that the question boils down to "if I buy a cheap 100W capable inverter, and replace the transformer for a higher-rated one, do I get a 1000W capable inverter?" No other interpretation of the question would make much sense IMO.

Answer (score 6):

No, changing the transformer alone is not sufficient. You also have to upgrade the switching devices that create the AC that drives the transformer. Typically, those are MOSFET transistors, and you then have to find bigger/faster MOSFETs. Such MOSFETs, in turn, typically need bigger/faster driver chips to pump enough charge into the gates to avoid heating up, so you also have to replace the driver circuits.

Then there's the issue of built-in protections -- often, there are Hall current sensors or sense resistors that determine the current draw on the inverter, and shuts down in case of over-current, to protect both the inverter and the surroundings. Even if you replace all the power electrnics, the control electronics will likely not be aware of the change, and thus shut down before you reach the higher wattage you want.

So, no. Inverters (and most other electronics) are generally designed as matched systems, where each part is good enough for what it does, but doesn't have too much wasted capacity. Using a bigger part than necessary will just increase price for no good reason. If you want a bigger inverter, buy a bigger inverter.

Answer (score 0):

What defines "bigger"? Transformers have a lot of variables: turns ratio, core composition, wire gauge, etc. If you simply changed a transformer for one with a different turns ratio, you would get a different output current and voltage, but that's probably not what you want. In the case of many consumer electronics, a transformer is usually coupled with a linear regulator/buck converter, which brings the voltage down to a specific point. Power is a function of both voltage and max current draw. So, short answer is: you'd need to know more about the circuit you're working with. It's not as simple as "drop it in, get more power".