# Replacement transistor for stereo receiver

Tags: transistors

Can I replace a 130w transistor with a 150w transistor in a Onkyo receiver.

Looking at this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/71432/if-i-change-the-transformer-on-my-inverter-for-a-bigger-one-will-it-increase-th/71435#71435) the first response -

> No, changing the transformer alone is not sufficient. You also have to
>   upgrade the switching devices that create the AC that drives the
>   transformer. Typically, those are MOSFET transistors, and you then
>   have to find bigger/faster MOSFETs. Such MOSFETs, in turn, typically
>   need bigger/faster driver chips to pump enough charge into the gates
>   to avoid heating up, so you also have to replace the driver circuits.
>
> Then there's the issue of built-in protections -- often, there are
>   Hall current sensors or sense resistors that determine the current
>   draw on the inverter, and shuts down in case of over-current, to
>   protect both the inverter and the surroundings. Even if you replace
>   all the power electrnics, the control electronics will likely not be
>   aware of the change, and thus shut down before you reach the higher
>   wattage you want.
>
> So, no. Inverters **(and most other electronics)** are generally designed
>   as matched systems, where each part is good enough for what it does,
>   but doesn't have too much wasted capacity. Using a bigger part than
>   necessary will just increase price for no good reason. If you want a
>   bigger inverter, buy a bigger inverter.

but this was about an inverter. The only reason I'm asking this question because the original transistors on ebay are used. Which to me sounds questionable, but Toshiba recommends a newer transistor but it has a higher wattage and I don't really feel like ripping this stereo apart again.

MY FIRST QUESTION

> I recently burnt up one of the channels on an Onkyo receiver, which is
>   the third time that this has happened. The warranty ran out and was
>   hoping I could re-solder new transistors in myself. Now the original
>   transistors that were in the unit were Toshiba A1962 and underneath
>   the part number was  a 0 then 840 which when I look at the data sheet
>   0 is a characteristics indicator and 840 is a lot number. When I sent
>   it into a professional electronics repair shop under warranty they
>   replaced two transistors, 1 with a Toshiba A1962 (0 characteristic 027
>   lot no.) and 1 Toshiba C5242 (0 characteristic and 948 lot no.).
>
> When I looked up the
>   [A1962](http://www.semicon.toshiba.co.jp/info/lookup.jsp?pid=2SA1962&lang=en)
>   on Toshibas site they said they are replacing it with new designs and
>   the
>   [2SA1943N](http://www.semicon.toshiba.co.jp/info/lookup.jsp?pid=2SA1943N&lang=en)
>   is recommended. Now the recommended part is rated at 150w while the
>   older is 130w I believe.
>
> All in all I am not an electrical engineer, but I think I can solder 2
>   transistors to a board but I'm unsure off which ones are required.

Comment: For a high power amplifier, I would order the transistors from Onkyo.  The manufacturer may have specially selected or matched them.  Perhaps the reason you've had additional failures is that the repair center did not buy the transistors from Onkyo.

Comment: I disagree with the hold. Sure, his original problem description is about consumer electronic repair... But his ultimate question is "Can I replace this specific transistor with this other specific transistor?" The *consumer electronics* part is just backstory & extra details, which everyone here is quick to ask for anyways if not originally provided.

Comment: When you have blown transistors in an amplifier, you can't just replace those transistors, because other transistors in the same circuit may have damage, such as the driver transistors (the transistors before the power transistors).  In addition, in a push-pull output stage such as a complementary one, you should probably change transistors in pairs even if it appears that only one blew.  Also, if the devices are attached to a heat sink with heat sink compound in between, clean out the old compound and replace it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you've blown the originals 3 times, it seems like a chancy proposition to keep on using the original devices, but you can certainly do it. Go search on eBay - there are several offers.

Otherwise, get the recommended replacement.

And, if you haven't done this sort of thing much, you'll need, in addition to a soldering iron and some solder, some solder wick to soak up the remnant solder after you remove the transistors.

Comment: And **not** acid core solder.

Comment: *"it seems like a chancy proposition to keep on using the original devices"*:  On the contrary, it's entirely possible that the reason the OP has experienced 2 additional failures is that the repair center did not use original Onkyo (selected) parts but purchased parts with the same part number from 'unapproved' sources.  Especially for high power circuits,  it is often the case that manufacturer selected parts (to whatever specs, matching, etc.) must be used for reliability.

Comment: Fair enough. And since the OP does not seem to have access to the matching criteria, that would seem to make any effort on his part to install unmatched original parts, well, a chancy proposition.

Comment: btw it was a faulty sub-woofer power supply that came with the receiver that was causing the channel to burn up.

Answer (score 1):

If the power rating is the only difference, then you should be able to use the 2SA1943N without any problem.

The power rating just means the device will survive if dissipating **up to** that much power.  If you exceed that rating, all bets are off.  This doesn't mean that it will try to always pull that much power; in fact, I would guess the nominal value to be be much less (and in a good design it should be).

So, the circuit was designed for a transistor rated up to 130W.  Now you want to replace it with a transistor that can handle 150W... Congratulations, you just bought yourself some more head room. It's possible that this might alleviate your blowing transistors problem... but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: The 130 or 150 will blow if there some other problem, like "dried up" heat sink compound or whatever.